# Posting an (more explained) answer to already answered question

Tags: discussion, answers

Recetly, I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29163423/2173917) in which OP provided a code snippet asking to clarify the reason of the weird output (s)he was getting. OP had a numbered list of q's in the question.

Now, while the question was already answered nicely, I felt that adding one more answer addressing question-by-question and explaining the logic *may* help OP to understand better. IMHO, other answer(s) rightly pointer out the errors in the code, but I feel my answer is more directed towards the logical explanation.

Upon posting my answer, I received a comment saying

> Why repeating an explanation that has already been given twice ?

and a downvote. Now I don't know the reason behind downvote but ***if*** it is due to the reason as per the comment, then is it justified?

<sup>P.S - [To the commentator] I have no intention to offend you sir, rather I want to thank you for taking time to leave a comment. I just want a small clarification for my future course of action, like whether to add an answer to already answerd question or not.</sup>

I think my questions boil down to :

1) Am I correct in thinking that my answer is useful?

2) If 1) is yes, then should I add such answers in future?

Comment: I certainly don't see any problem in adding another answer, **if** it's more clarifying on the same topic, or clarifying a not-yet-addressed point, or in clear *other wording* (i.e. not just a repeat of what's already posted). For me, your own example falls under this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reiterating [my comment under your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163423/while-loop-keeps-iterating-unexpectedly#comment46548336_29163771):

> It's not exactly the same explanation. Different views on the same topic are useful, because you never know which way of explaining the problem someone will find helpful, being fit to their knowledge, language, ways of reasoning, etc.

So, even though I wouldn't post such an answer myself, I think it's all right in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is not "not useful", and I do not believe it warrants any downvotes.

---

However, in the future, when you're about to answer an already well-answered question, consider the following:

If you're posting an answer to an already well-answered question, you should be absolutely *certain* that your answer actually goes well above and beyond the answer you're pointing.  You have to be certain your answer is as nice as you say it is.

In this specific case, your answer doesn't add anything that [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29163597/2792531) and [chmike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29163631/2792531) didn't already explain.

I don't think that necessarily warrants a downvote, but it certainly doesn't warrant any upvotes.  Your answer doesn't explain any more than either of these answers, and what your answer does explain, it doesn't do a better job of explaining than the already posted answers.

Personally, I regularly post answers which, in summary, might be about the same as an existing answer.  But when I do this, it's because I don't feel the existing answer sufficiently explained the problem, even if it provided the correct solution.  And when I do this, I'm trying to be reasonably certain that someone reading the question & answer might care about the answer.

Consider [this answer I posted over *Jon Skeet*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922252/2792531)!  Jon's answer is pretty good.  But my answer goes into a bit more detail.  I posted my answer an hour and a half after Jon's answer, and yet I've got 3 times as many upvotes as him.  People don't have a problem upvoting an answer to a question that was already answered.  People have a problem upvoting an answer that repeats what was already said without adding value (because it feels like you're just stealing rep points away from people who already posted the answers that cover it).

Length isn't necessarily going to be everything, but if you're posting an answer that isn't addressing a new issue (every point in your answer has already been made in another answer) and your answer isn't any *longer* than the other answers, then chances are good that your answer is neither a complete answer which accumulates all the other answers into one (which should probably be a community wiki answer) nor is it very likely that your answer goes into more detail explaining the points.

In the case of your specific answer, you should've just upvoted Lundin and chmike's answers and moved on.

Comment: 1) downvoting an asnwer means `"This anser is not useful"`. is it the case for my answer? 2) `but it certainly doesn't warrant any upvotes.` I never asked for any. If anyone finds my explanation useful, they'll do, otherwise no. I had query with the (possible) reason  behind downvote and the comment.

Comment: 3) ` doesn't add anything that Lundin and chmike didn't already explain.` Well, I think it does. No offense, but sometimes a little more __theoritical__ explanation _may_ help someone to understand the _logic_ better.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I agree that theoretical explanation can help. I just don't think your answer does a really good job of saying anything or explaining any better. Did you compare the answers that I linked to?

Comment: @SouravGhosh btw, I don't think your answer warrants a downvote. I'm with you there. But if you're going to answer an already answered question, perhaps put quite a bit more effort than existing answers. You missed your chance for the quick explanation, but you can still post the really in-depth over-explanation answer, which the question you answered is still lacking. You can edit your answer into one I'd upvote if you made the effort.